How to determine if $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a square
I want to determine if a element $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a square. To do that I learned the following:
Define $\mu:({-1,+1}, \cdot) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+), 1 \mapsto \overline{0}, -1\mapsto \overline{1}$.
Let $p \in \mathbb{P} \setminus \{2\}$, the map
$\Phi_p : \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$,
$up^n \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times^2} \mapsto(\mu((\frac{u}{p})),n \mod 2)$ with $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is a Isomorphism.
Where the Symbol $\biggl( \frac{u}{p} \biggr)$ for $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times} $ is to be interpreted as $u$ modulo $p$ and thus as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
This is followed by this example:
We will determine if $x=833$ is a suqare in $\mathbb{Q}_7$. We can write $833$ as $7^2 \cdot 17$ and calculate
$(*)$ $\biggl( \frac{17}{7} \biggr)=-\biggl( \frac{7}{3} \biggr)=-\biggl( \frac{1}{3} \biggr)=-1$.
Thus $\Phi_7=(\overline{1},\overline{0})$ and $x$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_7$.
My main Problem is that I do not understand the example.
Here is what I got for $x=833$:
Writing $833$ as $7^2 \times 17$, we can apply $\Phi_7$ on it.
Where $n=2, u=17,p=7$. Since $2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$ I get why the second component of $\Phi_7$ is $\mathbb{0}$.
So I assume that the calculation $(*)$ is to determine the first componen of $\Phi_7$. I need to calculate $\biggl( \frac{17}{7}\biggr)$, since $17 \mod 7 =3$ I get $\biggl( \frac{17}{7}\biggr)=\biggl( \frac{3}{7}\biggr)$. Well except it is stated that I should view $\biggl( \frac{17}{7}\biggr)$ only as $17 \mod 7$ and thus as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/7 \mathbb{Z}$, so calculating $\biggl( \frac{17}{7}\biggr)$ yields $\overline{3}$ as a result. By the Theorem I need to apply $\mu$ to it. But $\mu$ isn't defined for $\overline{3}$.
That's how far I got. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how the calculation in $(*)$ work.

$\left(\frac{u}{p}\right)$ should be interpreted as the Legendre symbol:
$$\left(\frac{u}{p}\right) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } u \equiv \square \bmod p\\
-1 & \text{if } u \not\equiv \square \bmod p
\end{cases}$$
where the notation $u\equiv \square \bmod p$ means $u$ is a square mod $p$ (and similar for $u \not\equiv \square \bmod p$). This symbol is defined for residue classes mod $p$, so all that matters in computing it is the class of $u \bmod p$.
For your specific example, we have $17 \equiv 3 \bmod 7$ so
$$\left(\frac{17}{7}\right) = \left(\frac{3}{7}\right).$$
At this point one could manually check that the square classes mod $7$ are $1,2,4$ and so $17\equiv 3\not\equiv \square \bmod 7$. However, we can also proceed as in the given computation and use the law of Quadratic Reciprocity: since $3,7$ are both equivalent to $3\bmod 4$ we have
$$\left(\frac{3}{7}\right) = -\left(\frac{7}{3}\right) = -\left(\frac{1}{3}\right).$$
Now $1 \equiv 1^2\bmod 3$ so the final result is
$$\left(\frac{17}{7}\right) = -\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) = -1.$$
